# We need to add values to combobox by selecting values from other combobox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, combobox

We need to add values to combo box by selecting values from another combo box.
It does not select values as it should. Only the first if part executes.
Here is the code:
it does not work for us.

```
    private void section_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string selected = (string)section.SelectedItem;

        if(selected == "Giftarticles")
        {
            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connString);
            conn1.Open();
            string itemc = "(select  distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'G%' )except(select  distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'H%')";
            SqlCommand cmditem = new SqlCommand(itemc, conn1);
            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmditem.ExecuteReader();

             while (dr2.Read())
            {
                itemcode.Items.Add(dr2["Itemcode"].ToString());
            }
            dr2.Close();
            conn1.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connString);
            conn2.Open();
            string itemc1 = "(select  distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'H%')except(select  distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'G%')";
            SqlCommand cmditem = new SqlCommand(itemc1, conn2);
            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmditem.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                itemcode.Items.Add(dr2["Itemcode"].ToString());
            }
            dr2.Close();
            conn2.Close();
}
    }
```

Comment: Did you make sure your 2nd query runs and produces correct results?

Comment: asp.net or windows application ?

Comment: If Asp.Net is it WebForms or MVC. If windows app, is it WinForm or WPF or WinRT?

Comment: BTW, you could replace EXCEPT with a more economical "select distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'H%' AND Section1 NOT like 'H%'"

Comment: May be my understanding of querry is incorrect. Still look into this.
Why do you need except part here? Means  when the following expression "Section1 like 'G%'" is evaluated, you will get codes that are has section only starting with G and has anything after that, so except part might not be needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I see that, actual need of if is between

```
        string itemc = "(select  distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'G%' )except(select  distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'H%')";
```

and

```
        string itemc1 = "(select  distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'H%')except(select  distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'G%')";
```

.

Excpt these two, the rest appears same. So only the query must be not returning results to you. Run those queries independently and see if you get results for the secon one.

Answer (score 0):

Although I hate making use of Connection, Reader etc. directly in the code and would advice going the Typed DataSet way, here is what should work for you:

```
private void section_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selected = (string)section.SelectedItem;
    using(SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn1.Open();
        string itemc = "select  distinct Itemcode from Items where Section1 like 'G%'";

        if(selected != "Giftarticles") itemc += " AND Section1 NOT LIKE 'H%'"

        SqlCommand cmditem = new SqlCommand(itemc, conn1);
        SqlDataReader dr2 = cmditem.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr2.Read())
            itemcode.Items.Add(dr2["Itemcode"].ToString());

        dr2.Close();
        conn1.Close();
    }
}
```

Replace your entire above code with this.